# Elasticsearch search time consistency

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very simple question.

I have an elasticsearch index containing 1600000 relatively large documents, and i need to scan the index to synchronize it with a classic sql database.

My documents include the sql ID and timestamp.

Then to synchronize the sql db and the elastic index, i simply read rows and documents sequentially, both sorted by id, and comparing the ids i can determine if i need to delete the document (comparison is negative), add a new document with the sql row (comparison is positive), and if comparison is 0 i compare the timestamps to know if i need to update the document.

It works but i observe that reading the documents gets a lot slower as i advance reading.

I retrieve my documents in chunks by repeating searches on the index, shifting the "from" field of the request each time, something like this :

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10000,
    "fields" : ["idannonce","ts"],
    "sort" : ["idannonce"],
    "query" : "match_all" {}
}
```

This simple query is a lot slower when "from" is 1000000 than when it is 0.

Is this normal behaviour ? I thought that it should take aproximately the same time as the "idannonce" field should be indexed, no ?

Any thought ?
Is there a way to write the same query so that it runs in a constant time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search API wasn't designed for this use case. Besides getting suboptimal performance you are, probably, also missing some changes since your deletions and additions are interfering with elasticsearch results by "shifting" your retrieval window when changes are committed to the index. You should switch to [Scroll API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/scroll.html), which much better suited for this operation.

Comment: I was hoping to use the Scroll API but sadly it doesn't support sorting. Using the Search API i can sort my documents by idannonce. Also, i'm not missing any insert/delete as the synchronization process runs in two passes. First i detemine the delta between sql db and elastic index using just ids and timestamps, then i retrieve the full datas for the delta from sql and insert/update/delete my docs as needed. Now i still don't understand why my queries run slower when "from" is high. Any idea ?

Comment: Scroll is typically used with scan search type, which indeed doesn't support sorting. However, you can use scroll with other search types as well. It might be more efficient though to pull all ids first without sorting and then sort them on your client. To answer your question about slow down, retrieval of further pages is slower because elasticsearh has to perform more work. Your index is split into multiple shards, right? So, now imagine, you have 5 sorted lists located on different nodes and I want you to retrieve records from 999,990 to 1,000,000 from a combined list. How would you do it?

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know it is possible to use the Scroll API with other search types than scan. I'll probably give it a try next week, for now i switched to range query, i remember the last id i found and restart the search from this id. This is not too slow but i hopr the scroll will be faster.

Comment: I fail to make the scroll work with sorting, it doesn't take my sorting criteria into account. Can you give me a simple query/url example that is suposed to do the job please ? Thanks

Comment: That's the query that should work: http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?q=*:*&scroll=10m&size=100&sort= idannonce Post your query somewhere and we can try to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Excellent, it seems to be working now, i was using the wrong syntax. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was also doing the similar thing but I found https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc more useful. It is very simple integration. Please try using this. 
Please post your code gist. Also  https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk observe the graphs when you are running your queries.

Comment: Looks cool !! I don't think i can use it because i need to manipulate the datas in a quite specific way but the jdbc river is something i could use for another task.